# Change the Height of an ExtJS 4 Tab

Tags: tabs, size, height, extjs4, tabpanel

---

*Context:* I'm writing an ExtJS application to help volunteers manage a camp database. Containing emergency information, dietary requirements and cabin allocation. I want it to be user-friendly so that volunteers will pick it up quickly, so I decided the tabs need to be **bigger** to draw attention to the **main actions** of the application.

*Problem:* I just don't know how to change the tab height though.

*Work so far:*

- I've tried setting the tabBar property for my tab panel, but the tabs didn't resize and the styling just looked weird
- I looked through forums and people suggested modifying the CSS, but there were **no examples**

---

Can you help? This is what I want to acheive:

http://tinypic.com/r/sltr9g/7

http://postimage.org/image/10x22n8ec/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I've found a solution!

Ensure you have set the 'cls' property of the Ext.tab.Panel you're using, then paste the following into your custom CSS file.

```
.MainPanel .x-tab-bar-strip {
    top: 40px !important; /* Default value is 20, we add 20 = 40 */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body {
    height: 43px !important; /* Default value is 23, we add 20 = 43 */
    border: 0 !important; /* Overides the border that appears on resizing the grid */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body .x-box-inner {
    height: 41px !important; /* Default value is 21, we add 20 = 41 */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body .x-box-inner .x-tab {
    height: 41px !important; /* Default value is 21, we add 20 = 41 */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body .x-box-inner .x-tab button {
    height: 33px !important; /* Default value 13, we add 20 = 33 */
    line-height: 33px !important; /* Default value 13, we add 20 = 33 */
}
```

Note this makes the tabs bigger and middle-aligns the text, but ideally the icon would **also be middle-aligned**.

Comment: You'll need to add 'MainPanel' as class in your TabPanel definition.

Comment: Extremely helpful--thanks for taking the time to post your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using [new ExtJS 4 theming with Compass](http://www.sencha.com/learn/theming/) you can just set:

```
$tab-height: 40px !default;
```

in `appname/resources/sass/my-ext-theme.scss`.

The only issue you will encounter is [extra space below tab bar bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141972-Bug-in-tab-panel-when-using-Sass-and-Compass), which always appears when using custom theme. But this can be solved easily, as explained there, by setting in one of your CSS:

```
.x-tab-bar
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

In `resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/variables/_tabs.scss` file in ExtJS package, you can find other useful variables to customize tab size and color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using extjs4 do use the SASS and Compass to make *any* changes in the extjs stylesheet.

You can just add below variable in my-custom-theme.scss to change the height of the tab:

```
$tab-height: 40px;
```