# Insert Component into the Tabpanel's tab in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to make a tabpanel in ExtJS 4 with big tab that include my own Component (or XTemplete),
is there some way to implement?
thanks

**UPDATE**
: can change the custom tab's height by this link

[Change the Height of an ExtJS 4 Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237795/change-the-height-of-an-extjs-4-tab)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you want exactly. Should the tab always contains a XTemplate by default? ExtJS has a great class system, so you can inherit from any class to build your own one or simply extend one at creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Ext.tab.Bar` and `Ext.tab.Tab`. You can pass in a tab bar configuration to the panel via the `Ext.tab.Panel#tabBar` config property.

```
var tabpanel = {
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    tabBar: {
        defaultType: 'xxx'        
    }
}​
```

You then create a custom component class with `alias: 'widget.xxx`. The default `Ext.tab.Tab` is a subclass of `Ext.button.Button` with custom styling.

Replacing it with a component that is not just a subclass of `Ext.tab.Tab` is probably quite a bit of work. You will need to assure that the component's behavior is correct and also the CSS styling looks nice.

A faster but less flexible approach would be to subclass `Ext.tab.Tab` and change its appearance to match your needs.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately ExtJs' `Ext.tab.Panel` explicitely sets the xtype for each tab that is being added/created.
From `Ext.tab.Panel`

```
onAdd: function(item, index) {
    var me = this,
        cfg = item.tabConfig || {},
        defaultConfig = {
            xtype: 'tab',                // <= XXX
            card: item,
            disabled: item.disabled,
            closable: item.closable,
```

But as you can see it is possible to add a `tabConfig` on the items of a tab panel which will take precedence of the defaultConfig defined here. So a simple and straight forward approach is to define a tabConfig on every child item of your tab panel

```
tabConfig: {
   xtype: 'xxx'
}
```

Comment: Hi, but it seems no change when setting defaultType in Ext JS 4

Comment: That is unfortunate. After checking the source I found that `Ext.tab.Panel` actually explicitely sets the `xtype` for each tab that is being constructed/added. I will update my answer to reflect that.